# environment variables not available to supervisor-run celery workers

Tags: python, environment-variables, celery, supervisord

I have been having trouble reading environment variables in some Celery Tasks when celery is run via supervisor

in `/etc/supervisord.conf` ...

```
...
[program:celery]
...
command = /home/myuser/mydevelopment/git/ers_data_app/env/bin/celery worker -A webapp.celery --loglevel=info
stdout_logfile=/home/webdev/logs/celeryworker.log
stderr_logfile=/home/myuser/logs/celeryworkererr.log
environment=FLASK_CONFIG="testing"
```

in `myapp/myfile.py` ...

```
...
print 'the system config is', os.getenv('FLASK_CONFIG')
dburi = app_config.config[os.getenv('FLASK_CONFIG')].DATABASE_URI
```

in `celeryworker.log` ...

```
the system config is None
```

in `celeryworkererr.log` ...

```
...
File "/home/webdev/mydevelopment/git/ers_data_app/webapp/dbmodels/database.py", line 16, in <module>
    dburi = app_config.config[os.getenv('FLASK_CONFIG')].DATABASE_URI
KeyError: None
```

Since `supervisor` doesn't start a shell, the following is unnecessary, but its here for completeness..

in `/etc/profile.d/my_app.sh`

```
export FLASK_CONFIG='testing'
```

Comment: try dumping `os.environ` to the log file - there may be some clues in there

Answer (score 0):

In your .conf file under the supervisord block, you can add all the environment key=value pairs as such

```
[supervisord]
environment=CELERY_BROKER_URL="amqp://guest:guest@127.0.0.1:5672//",FLASK_CONFIG="TESTING"

[program:celeryd]
command=celery worker -A celery --loglevel=info -P gevent -c 1000
```

If you dont want to hardcode the variables but want to pull it in from the os environment, step 1 on your bash

**Export env var**

```
>> sudo export CELERY_BROKER_URL="amqp://guest:guest@127.0.0.1:5672//"
```

**Reload Bash**

```
>> . ~/.bashrc
```

**Check if env vars are set properly**

```
>> env
```

**Now modify the conf file to read** - [Note](http://supervisord.org/configuration.html#environment-variables): prepend your env variables with ENV_

```
[supervisord]
environment=CELERY_BROKER_URL="%(ENV_CELERY_BROKER_URL)s",FLASK_CONFIG="%(ENV_FLASK_CONFIG)s"

[program:celeryd]
command=celery worker -A celery --loglevel=info -P gevent -c 1000
```